# Exclamation Point Error?

Tags: android, eclipse, compiler-errors, adt

I would like to ask on what to do when I got an Exclamation Point on all of my projects? A while ago it was going smoothly while doing my project and I'm installing an SDK Tool Update in the process then the Exclamation Point beside the project folder appear then it always says I got an error on my project but I don't have any as you can see in the image below.

[image]

Comment: This is more than likely a problem with your build path. Right click your project and hit properties. Go into your Java Build Path and check to see if dependencies are missing.

Comment: ohh the Android Dependencies got an error in the Java Build Path XD

Comment: Thanks inner_class7 got the answer all fixed now ^_^

Answer (score 0):

It generally happens when **no build target is set**. So do following steps.

1. Right click the Project
2. select Android and make sure that a Build Target is checked.

Sometimes you need to uncheck it select a different API, apply settings, and then again select the API that was originally selected

.

For more information see  [New Build path error](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.6-201006080911/eclipse-news-part2.html#JavaViews)

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you see these errors check your java build path for missing dependencies. Good luck!